# JSF- Customizing the growl message w.r.t.the primefaces TabMenu

Tags: java, jsf

I have two tabmenu in the tab namely XX,YY
I am following [primefaces tabmenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenuSupport.jsf)

I have a datatable inside the form "showdataForm" inside the XX tab where on loading, I am showing the number rows got loaded onload and displaying the message  example :"7 rows shown".

```
<h:form id="showdataForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
```

I am updating the above form "showdataForm" from backing bean using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 7 rows shown);
```

In the another TAB YY, I have another form "SystemDetailsinfoForm" having datatable which I use to show the rows only ON SEARCH. I am NOT SHOWING the rows in the datatable on load.
I am using

```
<h:form id="SystemDetailsinfoForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
```

for the form "SystemDetailsinfoForm"  which is inside the YY TAB

My problem is when I click the YY tab the page is getting refreshed but the Growl message  "7 rows shown" which is suppose to show only for the TAB XX is also shown for the YY tab when its get refreshed.How to differentiate the Growl mesage showing for each and every tab based on the events happening inside the form.
Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `for` attribute in the `<p:growl>` component to target only the required tab/form.

```
<h:form id="showdataForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" for="showdataForm"/>
```

Then when you add a message, do it like so:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("showdataForm", "7 rows shown"); // pass the key used in for attr
```

You can set the target for the second growl in the same way.